# PHP Associative Array - Duplicating items rather than adding to existing array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to take the contents of two CSVs, extract only certain pieces of information, and have them stored in an array of associative arrays. Ultimately I'm dealing with exports of PC information, and am trying to create a single array of PC Names, each one being itself an associative array of attributes.

It seems to be working fine at first, however when I try to add attributes from the second source I'm seeing the attributes be added to a new array with the same name, rather than adding the attribute to the existing array.

The first set (works as expected):

```
if($_FILES['panda']['error'] == 0){
    $pandaExt = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['panda']['name'])));
    $pandaTmpName = $_FILES['panda']['tmp_name'];

    if($pandaExt === 'csv'){
        $pandaHandle = @fopen($pandaTmpName, "r");
        if ($pandaHandle) {
            fgetcsv($pandaHandle, 0, "\t");
            while (($row = fgetcsv($pandaHandle, 0, "\t")) !== false) {
                switch ($row[1]) {
                    case "Server":
                        $servers[$row[2]]["Name"] = $row[2];
                        break;
                    
                    default:
                        $computers[$row[2]]["Name"] = $row[2];
                        $computers[$row[2]]["Type"] = $row[1];
                        $computers[$row[2]]["AV"] = $row[20];
                        $computers[$row[2]]["OS"] = $row[14];
                        $computers[$row[2]]["LastUser"] = $row[40];
                        $computers[$row[2]]["LastSeen"] = $row[12];
                        break;
                }
            }
            fclose($pandaHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

The second export (creates duplicate arrays inside of $computers):

```
if($_FILES['ncentral']['error'] == 0){
    $ncentralExt = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['ncentral']['name'])));
    $ncentralTmpName = $_FILES['ncentral']['tmp_name'];

    if($ncentralExt === 'csv'){
        $ncentralHandle = @fopen($ncentralTmpName, "r");
        if ($ncentralHandle) {
            for($i=0;$i<7;$i++)
            {
                fgetcsv($ncentralHandle, 0, ",");
            }
            while (($row = fgetcsv($ncentralHandle, 0, ",")) !== false) {
                if($row[1] == "Application" && $row[2] == "Display Name")
                {
                    array_push($applications[$row[3]],$row[0]);
                }
                if($row[1] == "BIOS" && $row[2] == "Serial number")
                {
                    $computers[$row[0]]["Serial"] = $row[3];
                }
            }
            fclose($ncentralHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

The end result is the $computers array outputting:

```
[CADUSER-PC] => Array
    (
        [Name] => CADUSER-PC
        [Type] => Workstation
        [AV] => data
        [OS] => data
        [LastUser] => data
        [LastSeen] => data
    )
[CADUSER-PC] => Array
    (
        [Serial] => data
    )
```

I can't get my head around why it doesn't just add the Serial attribute to the original array. Any ideas?

Comment: It is _impossible_ to begin with, to have multiple items with the same key. So the only logical conclusion here is, that what you _think_ is the same key twice, are actually _different_ keys. You probably have some leading/trailing whitespace before or after one of those keys.

Comment: i can't have any idea without a similar csv you test this code over it. i may have other ideas to reduce  this lot of code to smaller , me , others

Comment: Thanks for the pointers guys. Turns out the two csv exports were using different encoding. All is now working as expected.